# Straightforward way to count number of windows up through PopUpManager?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, count, popupwindow

I'm using the PopUpManager to bring a bunch of event windows up.

I want to make it so that only one window can be open at a time, but I don't see anywhere in the code that tracks open windows to set up a conditional. I guess it just creates the windows and then sets them free?

Thinking about a windowCount variable that increments when I add a window and decrements when I remove one, but since the PopupManager is called in different classes I'd have to start throwing events all over the place. I can do that, but I'm wondering if there's a more straightforward method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [systemManager](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/managers/SystemManager.html) (rather than PopUpManager, go figure...) provides information on the currently opened popup windows.

If your popups are all model then you will be interested in '[systemManager.numModalWindows](http://file:///C:/flex/SDK/docs/mx/managers/SystemManager.html#numModalWindows)':

> The number of modal windows. Modal
>   windows don't allow clicking in
>   another windows which would normally
>   activate the FocusManager in that
>   window. The PopUpManager modifies this
>   count as it creates and destroys modal
>   windows.

Otherwise try out '[systemManager.popUpChildren](http://file:///C:/flex/SDK/docs/mx/managers/SystemManager.html#popUpChildren)':

> An list of the topMost (popup) windows
>   being parented by this ISystemManager.
>
> An ISystemManager has various types of
>   children, such as the Application,
>   popups, tooltips, and custom cursors.
>   You can access the top-most windows
>   through the popUpChildren property.
>
> The IChildList object has methods like
>   getChildAt() and properties like
>   numChildren. For example,
>   popUpChildren.numChildren gives the
>   number of topmost windows and you can
>   access them as
>   popUpChildren.getChildAt(i).

Comment: wow good to know! wouldnt have guessed.. and i was so excited about my new popUpDistrictManager class I was making. I guess there's no demand anymore

Comment: unfortunately i'm creating bordercontainers rather than windows with the pop-up manager and those don't seem to count as popUpChildren.. there's the numChildren property but it is not reliable (not totally sure what counts as a child, but there's often more than i can account for)

Answer (score 2):

I see a few options:

1) Make all your windows modal; so that the application can't be used until the window is closed.  This is a argument to the [createPopUp](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/managers/PopUpManager.html#createPopUp%28%29) method on the PopUpManager. Presumably you do not have Popups creating other popups.

2) Create your own Manager class, possibly an extension of the PopUpManager class that keeps track of all open windows.  Then you'd have a single source of all PopUps and could maintain them that way.

Comment: I had them modal originally but I hated the lag and blur effect... extending PopUpManager might be the easiest way to go.. thanks

Comment: wow, extending or even copying singletons is not for the faint of heart

Comment: @Damon you can remove blur and lag for modal windows using CSS. See the following styles `modalTransparency`, `modalTransparencyBlur`, `modalTransparencyColor` and `modalTransparencyDuration`. You can set new values in `global` styles.